# How to view Jmeter Assertion results in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, continuous-integration, automated-tests

I've created a Jmeter test plan containing a lot of samplers and a response Assertion for each one , Integrated it successfully with Jenkins

My Question:

Is there a way to configure the performance report to view  the number of successful vs failed sampler assertions in the performance report  or is there a better plugin for Jenkins to to so

Comment: In Jenkins, use below command `JMETER_HOME\jmeter.bat -J jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -n -t JMETER_HOME\<testplan>.jmx -l JMETER_HOME\<your-JTL>.jtl`. This will execute the test in NON-GUI mode. Once the test is done, launch JMeter and add your choice of listener and map the JTL to view the results. To view the success/failed assertion, add `Assertion Listener` to see the results. Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You should have "Percentage of errors" chart under the "Performance Trend" section:

[image: JMeter Jenkins percentage of erros]

Given you add an assertion to each sampler it should be enough to use this chart.

---

With regards to other options, depending on what you are trying to achieve you can also:

1. [Generate JMeter HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html), it comes with the statistics table. The dashboard can be displayed using i.e. [HTML Publisher Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin)
2. Run JMeter test via [JMeter Ant Task](http://www.programmerplanet.org/projects/jmeter-ant-task/) as a post processing step it transforms JMeter .jtl results file into single-page HTML report which has statistics and failed assertion details. See [Running a JMeter Test via Jenkins Pipeline - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-test-jenkins-pipeline-tutorial) for example configuration steps
3. Run your JMeter test using [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool as a wrapper, it has [JUnit XML Reporter](https://gettaurus.org/docs/Reporting/#JUnit-XML-Reporter) subsystem. It produces results which can be parsed by i.e. [Jenkins JUnit Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JUnit+Plugin)

Comment: Actually viewing the percentage of errors will not be useful for me as i need to know exactly which thread failed and which ones were successful

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trials and fails I found out a way to view passed , failed Jmeter Samplers in Jenkins

which is to Extract the result report to a .csv file

I did this by doing the following :

1- Add a View Results Tree listener to my test plan

2- I run the Jmeter in a NON GUI mode within Jenkins by including below command in the post build Action:

```
sh jmeter.sh -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=yyyy/MM/dd -n -t /path to the test plan/TestPlan.jmx -l test1.csv
```

After building the project there will be a performance report displaying all the samplers in my .jmx file  with the failed ones colored in Red

Note:

If you want to include the .CSV file in the notification Email aftre the project build you have to choose Which fields to be included in the output report and this is done by pressing Configure in the (Show Results In Tree) listener 
and choose what fields to be included in the file